# How to move the labels?

Tags: tikz-feynman

[image]I want the intermediate labels to be on the right or left (outside the diagram). How can I do it the simplest way? Here's my code

```
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
i1 [particle={\(\Xi^0\)}] -- [fermion] a [label=A] -- [fermion] i2 [crossed dot, label=B],
i2 -- [fermion] i3 [label=C],
i1 -- [draw=none] f1 [particle={\(n\)}],
i3 -- [charged scalar, label=\(\eta\)] f3 [label=G],
i4  [particle={\(D\)}] -- [draw=none] f4 [particle={\(\Lambda\)}],
a -- [charged scalar, edge label=\(\eta\)] b [label=E],
i2 -- [charged scalar, edge label=\(\eta\)] f2 [label=F],
f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 ,
f2 -- [fermion] f3,
f3 -- [fermion] f4,
i3 -- [fermion] i4,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the label position with e.g. `label=left:B`. Please consider in the future to post complete examples that start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{ i1 [particle={\(\Xi^0\)}] -- [fermion] 
a [label=left:A] -- [fermion] i2 [crossed dot, label=left:B], 
i2 -- [fermion] i3 [label=left:C], 
i1 -- [draw=none] f1 [particle={\(n\)}], 
i3 -- [charged scalar, label=(\eta)] f3 [label=right:G], 
i4 [particle={\(D\)}] -- [draw=none] f4 [particle={\(\Lambda\)}], 
a -- [charged scalar, edge label=\(\eta\)] b [label=right:E], 
i2 -- [charged scalar, edge label=\(\eta\)] f2 [label=right:F], 
f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 , 
f2 -- [fermion] f3, 
f3 -- [fermion] f4, 
i3 -- [fermion] i4, };
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible also to write below the A, for example?? thanks!

Comment: @AriadnaAixut You can replace `label=left:A` by `label=below:A` but then it will sit on top of the fermion line.

Comment: I mean to write a second line below. Like: A (above), uds (below)

Comment: @AriadnaAixut like `[label={[align=right]left:{A\\ $uds$}}]`?